# Setting Java Swing Color for a Canvas results in an incorrect grayscaled color

Tags: java, javafx, canvas

I am trying to fill a canvas with pixels of a certain color. For this, i am using

```
if (jFrame == null) {
            jFrame = new JFrame();
            canvas = new Canvas();
            jFrame.add(canvas);
            canvas.setSize(280, 280);
            jFrame.setSize(280, 280);
            jFrame.setVisible(true);
        }
        for (int x = 0; x < 28; x++) {
            for (int y = 0;y < 28; y++) {
                canvas.getGraphics().setColor(Color.BLUE);
                System.out.println(canvas.getGraphics().getColor());
                canvas.getGraphics().fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 10, 10);
            }
        }
```

This results me in a canvas which is entirely grey, not blue. When logging out `canvas.getGraphics().getColor()`, it result me with `sun.swing.PrintColorUIResource[r=51,g=51,b=51]`, which very clearly is not the color blue. Using `Color.RED` or any other Color for that matter (even custom constructed ones using `new Color(r, g, b)` still result me in having r,g,b = [51, 51, 51] which i do not understand.

I expected the canvas actually to be filled in the appropriate specified color, and the System.out.println call giving out the actual color i specified. Attached is an image of the gray canvas i am experiencing [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX8Zw.png)

Comment: You need to look at the custom painting Swing tutorials as at the moment you're doing it wrong. You should be overriding the key method of the component you're using. And there's no need to a loop. Just paint a rectangle of the correct size. Also, the components you're using have nothing to do with JavaFX, so I'm not sure why you tagged that

Comment: about that javaFX - not sure, i was certain it belonged there. And for the loop, in the end im trying to have every "block" have a different color. About the swing tutorials, yeah ill look into it, thank you

Comment: *in the end im trying to have every "block" have a different color* I can only go on what you've posted at the moment and there's only one color. You're using `java.awt.Canvas` right?

Comment: Are you using JavaFX or Swing? You must know what classes and what toolkit you yourself are using. This looks more like Swing (JavaFX Canvas does not have a `getGraphics()` method), but this isn't the correct way to use a `Canvas` in either toolkit.

Answer (score 1):

You have tagged this question `javafx` but the title says it is about a Swing canvas and the code is Swing code.

Assuming you are really talking about Swing, the [documentation for `Canvas`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Canvas.html) explicitly says

> An application must subclass the `Canvas` class in order to get useful functionality such as creating a custom component. The `paint` method must be overridden in order to perform custom graphics on the canvas.

The bottom line here is that the `Graphics` object returned by `Canvas.getGraphics()` is not the same one passed to the `paint()` method, on which graphics drawing is performed. Following the documentation has exactly the required effect.

Modifying your example slightly so it matches your comment ('in the end im trying to have every "block" have a different color') and making it into a complete example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class SwingCanvas {

    public SwingCanvas() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {
                for (int x = 0 ; x < 28 ; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0 ; y < 28; y++) {
                        g.setColor(Color.getHSBColor((x+y)/(2*28.0f), 1.0f, 1.0f));
                        g.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 10, 10);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        canvas.setSize(280, 280);
        frame.add(canvas);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(SwingCanvas::new);
    }
}
```

Which results in

[image]

If you did really mean JavaFX, then the following is the equivalent example in that framework:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(280,280);
        GraphicsContext g = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        for (int x = 0 ; x < 28 ; x++) {
            for (int y = 0 ; y < 28; y++) {
                g.setFill(Color.hsb(360.0*(x+y)/(2*28), 1.0, 1.0));
                g.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 10, 10);
            }
        }
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(canvas));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```